# Lazy loading images on mobile

Tags: javascript, jquery, lazy-loading, jquery-lazyload

I'm using this lazy loading code.

JS CODE:

```
$(window).on('scroll touchmove', function(){
  if( $('.touch').length) {
    var images = $('.theme-slider img[data-lazy]');
    images.each(function(index){
        if(isElementVisible(this)) {
            $(this).attr('src', $(this).attr('data-lazy'));
            $(this).removeAttr('data-lazy');
        }
    })
    if(images.length == 0) { 
        $(window).off('scroll touchmove');
    }
  }
});


// Checking if an image is within the viewport
function isElementVisible(el){ 
  var rect = el.getBoundingClientRect();
  return (
    rect.top >= 0 && 
    rect.left >= 0 &&
    rect.bottom <= (window.innerHeight) &&
    rect.right <= (window.innerWidth)   
  );    
}
```

My problem is on iPhone when I'm scrolling horizontal if the image has entered the viewport it doesn't load, I have to scroll back and forward until it works.
Any ideas how I can solve it?

Comment: I suggest using http://verlok.github.io/lazyload/

Comment: for jQuery there is https://github.com/tuupola/jquery_lazyload